# how can I know which Item was selected in listview + imagelist

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, selecteditem, imagelist

This is the fist time I post a question on this site and I need some help.
This is my code

```
private void loadMatrixOfTables()
{
    try
    {
        var tb = BaSic.db.tb_Tables; //load database with LINQ
        lsvTables.Clear(); //this is my lisview

        foreach (var b in tb)
        {
            if (b.Status == true)
            {
                lsvTables.Items.Add(b.Name,1);
            }
            else
            {
                lsvTables.Items.Add(b.Name, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

My table has 2 fields: id and name
What I need do to get item value, not item text.

Comment: are you looking for `SelectedIndexChanged` ?

Comment: my table has 2 column: id and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the type of **b** so the example is using the 2 known attributes id and string assuming that are an int and a string respectively . Just change them for your containing class.

First you need to create your own ListViewItem, to support show the *name* on the listView and get his *id* when is required. In your case it looks like this:

```
public class CustomListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
    public CustomListViewItem(int id,  string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Using it**

First create your item

`var item = new CustomListViewItem(id, name)`

To show in the listview the name just add:

`item.Text = name`

and then added to the listView:

`lsvTables.Items.Add(item,1)`

To retrieve the selected item's *id* just cast the selected item as CustomListViewItem. For example:

`int id = (CustomListViewItem)lsvTables.SelectedItems[0].Id;`

Comment: Glad to help.If you are so kind please accept my answer.